# Angular: update in factory model does not reflect in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a user preference factory that holds user preference values. When the page loads it is empty. After user logs in it is filled up with user profile. 
pseudo code

```
app.factory('pref', function($rootScope){
    var pref = {}, age, name;        
    $rootScope.$on('logged.in', function(){
      pref.name = 'sam';
      pref.age = 30;
      pref.currency = '$';

      age = getAge(); name = getName();
    })

    function getName(){
      //format name
      return name;
    }
    function getAge(){
      return age;
    }  
    return {
      currency: pref.currency,
      age: age,
      name: name
    }
  })
```

Then I inject the factory in my controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, pref) {
  $scope.name = pref.name; //Return undefined
  var currency = pref.currency;
  $scope.price = function(amount){
    return amount + currency; //don't show $ sign
  }
});
```

Return value from pref factory not updating in controller. How do I make it work?

Edit: plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/SKJC5hUPEm72JqGJyT9y

Comment: i dont see logged.in fired in your code could you tell at which location you are firing the event

Comment: Is it me or do you never set a value to name? pref.name in the controller calls getName() which returns name, but name then again calls getName()? pref.name is set, but that is a different object, not the one you return.

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal it's a psudo code. MY login service emits event when successful login happens and at that point values in `pref` object is set. until then pref is an empty object

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle or Plunker that shows the problem?  There could be any number of issues, and posting code that isn't the same as what you are having problems with doesn't really help anyone debug it.

Comment: @rtcherry added a plunker to illustrate the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object returned from the `pref` factory,

```
{ setPreference: setPreference,
  currency: pref.currency,
  name: pref.name,
  formatTime: formatTime }
```

assigns `currency` and `name` to undefined properties.  Since `undefined` is not a reference type, `currency` and `name` will not "see" any updates to object `pref`.

I suggest instead that a property that references the `pref` object be part of the object returned by the factory:

```
{ setPreference: setPreference,
  prefs: pref,
  formatTime: formatTime }
```

Now, any updates we make to `pref` will be reflected in `prefs`.  Refer to properties of that object as follows in your controller:

```
console.log(prefService.prefs.name)
```

In order to not change the reference that `pref` points to, use `angular.copy()` to modify the object that `pref` references:

```
function setPreference(values){
   //pref = values;   <<-- won't work, since pref will now reference another object
   angular.copy(values,pref);
}
```

**Update**: to have the view automatically update when the `name` changes, I suggest saving a reference to `prefs` as a scope property:

```
$scope.prefs = prefService.prefs;
```

Then use `{{prefs.name}}` in the view/HTML:

```
<p>Hello {{prefs.name}}!</p>
```

Updated <kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S73anzqXuF9Y1H4yURel?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I understand the problem. Now my service methods have updated values, however my scope properties still not updated. `$scope.name = prefService.prefs ? prefService.prefs.name : null;` `name` never gets updated in view

Comment: Thanks man that works perfect! One question though, why is it required to have it on scope? I'm assuming it has something to do with digest cycle but then again during dygest `$scope.name` should have evaluated `prefService.prefs.name`

Comment: @SamSerious, `$scope.name = prefService.prefs.name` assigns (copies) the primitive value of `prefService.prefs.name` to `$scope.name`.  `$scope.name` will not be updated in a digest cycle.  You would have to set up a `$watch()` for that to happen.  With `$scope.prefs = prefService.prefs`, we are dealing with a reference.  If the object that is referred to changes, the thing that references it will see the change -- this is a language/JavaScript feature.  Digest cycles aren't involved here either.