# View not updated when variable is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to create a client for information which is received via WebSockets (unimportant). The information is inside a JSON container.
I use

```
Buildings = JSON.parse(a_Data.data);
```

To parse the string to JSON and save that Javascript object to the variable called Buildings which resides in my factory. Afterwards that variable is being exposed to $scope correctly inside my controller.
However my view doesn't update at all (the update is not being triggered), while Buildings is being set correctly.
I read somewhere that this is because AngularJS just takes care of variables created by itself, which is why it was suggested to add an array to the array created by Angular (and forehand set the length of it to 0 to clear it). However in this case I have an object which is why the push trick won't work.
using

```
angular.fromJson
```

Doesn't change anything.
I also read that you can force that update more or less by using

```
$scope.$apply
```

Which however would require to pass $scope to the factory which I would like to avoid if possible.

(Adding the object to an Array is a working workaround, but it's not what I'm looking for, as soon as there is a way around that).

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket/v1.0.9/angular-websocket.js"></script>

  <script src="js/protocol.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="MiniGame">
  <section ng-controller="SomeController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="data in buildings">
        {{ data.type }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

</div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

The protocol.js

```
angular.module('MiniGame', ['ngWebSocket'])

.factory('GameProtocol', function($websocket, $q) {

    var socket = $websocket('ws://localhost:9002');
    var m_Buildings = { };
    console.log("Example ", m_Buildings);

    function Setup(){
        socket.onMessage(OnMessage);
        console.log("Startup complete");
    }

    function OnMessage( a_Data ){


        m_Buildings = angular.fromJson(a_Data.data);
        console.log(m_Buildings);
    }

    function RequestBuildings(){
        dataStream.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'GetBuildings' }));
    }

  return {
    Setup : Setup,
    buildings : m_Buildings
  };
})

.controller('SomeController', function ($scope, GameProtocol) {

      $scope.GameProtocol = GameProtocol;
      $scope.GameProtocol.Setup();
      $scope.buildings = GameProtocol.buildings;

    });
```

Comment: Please show service code and how you integrate with controller

Comment: I think the WebSocket code won't be much of a use, but I'll try to create a simple example which shows it.

Comment: Just post the code. That is a fundamental part of  asking questions here. Demos are great but for something like  a socket not easy to set up

Comment: The thing is I don't believe that the socket is the main cause and I think a demo which recreates the problem (without the need of the server) is even more useful as without the server it's impossible to actually send the JSON string. Also WebSockets works without promises so that shouldn't be a great deal there.

Comment: No it's not the actual socket connection...it's how you are integrating that matters. Without code can't help much

Comment: ok, I'm going to edit the post.

Comment: Your protocol is definitely the problem. Notice that after `OnMessage`, `GameProtocol.buildings` is still unchanged.

Comment: Shouldn't m_Buildings be bound to GameProtocol.buildings and therefor change it as well?
EDIT:
Actually got it to work, using angular.copy works, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270434/angular-update-in-factory-model-does-not-reflect-in-controller

Thanks for the help, else I wouldn't have found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
angular.copy(angular.fromJson(a_Data.data), m_Buildings);
```

Instead of

```
m_Buildings = angular.fromJson(a_Data.data);
```

fixes the problem.

For further details look at this answer.
[Angular: update in factory model does not reflect in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270434/angular-update-in-factory-model-does-not-reflect-in-controller)